# Spring Data GemFire 2.0.1.RELEASE is throwing an Initialization Error

Tags: spring-data-gemfire

Initially, my application was running fine with **spring-data-gemfire 1.9.7.RELEASE**.  However, after upgrading to **spring-data-gemfire 2.0.1.RELEASE**, my application fails to start and throws an Initialization Error as shown below:

> C:\Dev\projects\JavaWebClient\web\target>java -jar
>   web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> .   ____          _            __ _ _
>    /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
>
>   ( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
>
>    \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
>     '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
>    =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
>    :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.8.RELEASE)
>
> [info 2017/11/15 19:07:23.999 EAT  tid=0x1] Starting
>   JavaWebClientApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on MY-PC with PID 13804
>   (C:\Dev\projects\JavaWebClient\web\target\web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   started by edwards in C:\Dev\projects\JavaWebClient\web\target)
>
> [info 2017/11/15 19:07:24.019 EAT  tid=0x1] No active profile
>   set, falling back to default profiles: default
>
> [info 2017/11/15 19:07:24.812 EAT  tid=0x1] Refreshing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e6c3152:
>   startup date [Wed Nov 15 19:07:24 EAT 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy
>
> [error 2017/11/15 19:07:25.892 EAT  tid=0x1] Application startup
>   failed java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Optional;
>           at org.springframework.data.gemfire.repository.config.GemfireRepositoryConfigurationExtension.registerBeansForRoot(GemfireRepositoryConfigurationExtensi
>   on.java:120)
>           at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.
>   java:83)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$0(ConfigurationClassBeanDefini
>   tionReader.java:360)
>           at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReade
>   r.java:359)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefiniti
>   onReader.java:144)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:328)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.ja
>   va:273)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:693)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>           at com.nftconsult.gemfire.web.JavaWebClientApplication.main(JavaWebClientApplication.java:173)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>
> [info 2017/11/15 19:07:25.897 EAT  tid=0x1] Closing
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e6c3152:
>   startup date [Wed Nov 15 19:07:24 EAT 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy
>
> [warn 2017/11/15 19:07:25.901 EAT  tid=0x1] Exception thrown
>   from LifecycleProcessor on context close
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized -
>   call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e6c3152:
>   startup date [Wed Nov 15 19:07:24 EAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:433)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1004)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>           at com.nftconsult.gemfire.web.JavaWebClientApplication.main(JavaWebClientApplication.java:173)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>
> [error 2017/11/15 19:07:25.905 EAT  tid=0x1] Destroy method on
>   bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory
>   ' threw an exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before
>   multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6e6c3152:
>   startup date [Wed Nov 15 19:07:24 EAT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:420)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:95)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:240)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:576)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:552)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:521)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:227)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1035)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1011)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:963)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>           at com.nftconsult.gemfire.web.JavaWebClientApplication.main(JavaWebClientApplication.java:173)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>
> C:\Dev\projects\JavaWebClient\web\target>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not surprising since your *Spring* application is based on *Spring Boot* `1.5.8.RELEASE` and it isn't clear how you specifically upgraded the *Spring Data GemFire* dependency from `1.9.7.RELEASE` to `2.0.1.RELEASE`.

The problem is, you are pulling in an incompatible version of *Spring Data Commons* as well as, and I suspect, several other *Spring* dependencies (e.g. the core *Spring Framework*) since your applications is rooted in *Spring Boot* `1.5.8.RELEASE`.  Hence the **`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`** error...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Optional; 
at org.springframework.data.gemfire.repository.config.GemfireRepositoryConfigurationExtension.registerBeansForRoot(GemfireRepositoryConfigurationExtensi on.java:120)
```

First, you need to understand that all [Spring Data modules](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) (see "*Main modules*", "*Community modules*" and "*Related modules*" and the section about the "*Release train*" on the SD project page) build on a particular version of both *Spring Data Commons* and the core *Spring Framework*.  You **cannot** simply upgrade 1 dependency and not expect to have to upgrade others.

The SD Release Trains (such as [**Ingalls**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls) or [**Kay**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay)) are all based on a particular version of *Spring Data Commons* and the core *Spring Framework*.  For instance, with SD **Kay**, see "[*Core themes*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay#core-themes)" and "[*Participating modules*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay#participating-modules)".

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is specifically occurring because you are using an incompatible version of *Spring Data Commons* (i.e. SDC `1.13.8.RELEASE` from **Ingalls**, which is [pulled in](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L158) by *Spring Boot* **1.5.x**) with *Spring Data GemFire* `2.0.1.RELEASE`, which [comes from SD Kay](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay#participating-modules), and expects SDC `2.0.x.RELEASE`.

This class, (i.e. [`org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.html)) is a *Spring Data Commons* class.  Clearly the [method signature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.13.8.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) (i.e. `getAttribute(:String):String`) in SDC `1.13.8` (**Ingalls**) for the method in question is **not** what SDG `2.0.1.RELEASE` expects (i.e. `getAttribute(:String):Optional<String>`), which [comes from](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) SDC `2.0.1.RELEASE`.

There is a reason why *Spring Boot*, and by extension, the *Spring IO Platform*, **provide a curated and harmonized set of dependencies** that have all been **tested** and **proven to work together**.  When you deviate from the prescribed dependencies, you need to be mindful of this.

Technically, only the upcoming *Spring Boot* **2.0** release will be [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.0.M6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L150) SD **Kay**.

However, if you do need a GA release of *Spring Boot* (i.e. `1.5.8.RELEASE`, the current latest) and wish to use *Spring Data GemFire* `2.0.1.RELEASE`, or **Kay-SR1**, then fortunately you are in luck!

I too wanted to use *Spring Data* **Kay** with the latest GA version of *Spring Boot* (i.e. 1.5.8.RELEASE) in the [*Spring IO Guides*](https://spring.io/guides) (for [instance](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gemfire/)) to showcase the new features in *Spring Data GemFire* `2.0.x` **Kay**, since many things have changed for the better (like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config)).

I was able to get this to work, but I need to set specific things in the Maven (or Gradle) build file, such as [overriding the dependency versions of SD and the core *Spring Framework*](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-gemfire/blob/master/complete/pom.xml#L19-L20) managed by *Spring Boot* (specifically [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L154), and [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml#L158)).  Note [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-gemfire/blob/master/complete/pom.xml#L10) as well.  Also note my [dependencies](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-gemfire/blob/master/complete/pom.xml#L25-L38).

*Gradle* is a bit more tricky, but you can see the new build file [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-gemfire/blob/master/complete/build.gradle) and compare it with the previous version [here](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-gemfire/blob/012ae2f05a82f5b8fe1b42b103aedcf5ca8c206a/complete/build.gradle).

Anyway, keep these things in mind the next time you are wrangling dependency versions, which is the whole reason why *Spring IO Platform* was created in the first place, to manage all the dependencies and dependencies of dependencies (i.e. transitive dependencies) when possible overlap/conflicts occur (since certain transitive dependencies will have the same dependencies), etc, etc.

Hope this helps!

Regards,
-j

Comment: thank you very much indeed for such a detailed explanation. 
You're definitely right, the problem was due to pulling incompatible version of Spring Data Commons as well as other Spring Dependencies, which could not work with Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE and Spring Data Kay.

I was finally able to get my application up and running on Spring Data Kay with the latest GA version of Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, by simply setting the following things in my pom.xml file
spring.version to 5.0.1.RELEASE
spring-data-releasetrain.version to Kay-SR1
spring-shell.version to 1.2.0.RELEASE